# Javascript xor ^ with 0 return bad result

Tags: javascript, bit-manipulation, xor

I'm using the binary xor operator ^ with 2 variables like this :

```
var v1 = 0;
var v2 = 3834034524;
var result = v1 ^ v2;
```

The result is -460932772. 
Have you an idea why ?

Thank you

Comment: How is that unexpected?

Comment: `3834034524 > Math.pow(2,31) - 1 // true`

Comment: What is the point of doing that by the way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`3834034524`, as a 32bit *unsigned* integer is hex `E486B95C` or binary `11100100100001101011100101011100`. Notice that the most significant (leftmost) bit is set. This is the sign bit on 32bit *signed* integers.

There, that bit pattern translates to decimal `-460932772`. The XOR operation is forcing the result into signed integers.

Additional info: a 32bit *signed* integer can handle values from -2147483648 to +2147483647 (which your original value exceeded and it thus *wrapped around*). 32bit *unsigned* integers handle values from 0 to +4294967295. JavaScript is a dynamically typed language and the values may change types as needed. The number may become a floating point value, or bitwise operations may turn it into an integer, or it could become a string. There are some ways to use specific datatypes in recent versions of JavaScript, but this is not something you'd do with simple calculations.

Comment: Thank you, this is the explanation. This is not common in other languages.

Answer (score 6):

This is an expected behavior these are signed numbers.

Just truncate the result to an unsigned integer

```
var result = (v1 ^ v2) >>> 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

The [`ToInt32` operation](http://es5.github.io/#x9.5) does not preserve the sign - it casts your number to a signed 32-bit representation. Since 3834034524 is larger than 2<sup>31</sup>, it will overflow and result in a negative integer.

```
  010           --ToInt32-->  000000000000000000000000000000002
^ 383403452410  --ToInt32-->  111001001000011010111001010111002
                                         V xor V
= -46093277210  <-fromInt32-  111001001000011010111001010111002
```

Comment: "The ToInt32 operation does not preserve the sign" --- this phrase looks suspicious

Comment: @zerkms: Yeah, but I think it's quite accurate. Step 5 is "*If `int32bit` is greater than or equal to 2<sup>31</sup>, return `int32bit` − 2<sup>32</sup>, otherwise return `int32bit`*"